# Не учитывать margin при наведении на элемент

Tags: html, css

На странице есть N-ое количество одинаковых блоков, при наведении на которые они подсвечиваются, у блоков установлено свойство margin. Проблема в том, что и при наведении на margin блок так же подсвечивается, то есть визуально получается наведение вне области блока, но эффект срабатывает. Как можно исправить?

Comment: покажите код!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, margin не учитывается при hover. Скорее всего у вас hover висит не на самом элементе, а на обертке.

Comment: В качестве доказательства: http://jsfiddle.net/HDyW8/

Comment: Спасибо, затупил немного. hover распространялся и на элементы установленного плагина, из-за чего возникало ощущение, что и margin учитывается при наведении.